# How to open json file with objects in d3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to load one json file for a d3 world map (based on: http://datamaps.github.io/) and a d3 bar chart (based on: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
"CHE":  {"costOfLivingIndex": "123.10", "propertyPriceToIncomeRatio": "123.10", "qualityOfLifeIndex": "208.54", "name": "Switzerland", "purchasingPower": "178.74", "pollutionIndex": "28.73", "trafficCommuteTimeIndex": "8.57", "health Care Index": "68.88", "climateIndex": "23.02", "safetyIndex": "74.27"},
"DNK":  {"costOfLivingIndex": "84.88", "propertyPriceToIncomeRatio": "84.88", "qualityOfLifeIndex": "206.49", "name": "Denmark", "purchasingPower": "142.14", "pollutionIndex": "25.64", "trafficCommuteTimeIndex": "5.85", "health Care Index": "81.89", "climateIndex": "29.93", "safetyIndex": "74.33"}
etc...
}
```

I choose this lay for the d3 world map. However, how I am wondering how I can iterate through properties of the objects. If I do for instance:

```
console.log(data.DNK.name);
```

I get the name, but how can get a list with all the names (or other values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we you could do something like:

```
for (var key in data) {
    alert(key + " -> " + data[key]);
}
```

you should be able to get the other parameters via data[key]

Answer (score 0):

As it is already JSON object you can loop through it without using `JSON.parse` which you would use if it were string or sth.

```
for(var key in data){
  console.log(key); 
    for(var k in data[key]){
      console.log(k,data[key][k]);
    }
}
```